# Change "dist" folder to root in Zurb 6

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

Does anyone know how to change the `"dist"` folder for Zurb 6 to be the top level of the site, i.e. so the output would be the same level as `"src"`?

In config.yml I have tried changing `"dist"` to `""` but am not sure what else to try.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference Zurb Foundation 6:

File: config.yml

```
PATHS:
  dist: "dist" // change this to new folder ROOT "./"
```

**IMPORTANT:**

File: gulpfile.babel.js

```
// Delete the "dist" folder
// This happens every time a build starts
function clean(done) {
  rimraf(PATHS.dist, done);
}
```

So if you change to the PATHS.dist to ./ it will actually delete the whole project.

You DO NOT NEED to access **./src** FROM **dist/** as the **./src** gets compiled to **./dist/assets**.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly. But you can use the standard unix format to go up one level.

So change in your config.yml file:

```
dist: "dist"
```

to

```
dist: "../dist"
```